# Postgresql: Query Between time range using jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with two fields:

```
id(serial), data(jsonb)
```

And into data I have records with a Datetime field stored as UNIX timestamps:

```
{"Device":132,"Datetime": 1434166552,...}
```

I'm trying to query between ranges:

```
SELECT *
FROM trips
WHERE data->>'Datetime' BETWEEN
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2014-04-01') AND
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2014-04-15' + interval '1 day')
    AND id = 123
```

Message

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text >= double precision
LINE 3: WHERE data->>'Datetime' BETWEEN
```

Something I'm doing wrong, please cloud somebody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `->>` operator returns an JSON object field as `text` (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)). You need to cast it :

```
SELECT *
FROM trips
WHERE (data->>'Datetime')::int 
  BETWEEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2014-04-01') 
      AND EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2014-04-15' + interval '1 day')
  AND id = 123
```

Comment: Why not `data::json->>'Datetime'` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `data` is already a `json` (or `jsonb`, but it doesn't change anything here), what would `::json` do ?

Comment: I thought It will return integer, because `->>` is int?

Comment: The `json`/`jsonb` operator `->>` returns a `text` (see the link in the answer).