# Rails 5 search jsonb nested array for date between 2 other dats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to craft a query for searching a jsonb field in Ruby on Rails 5, I need to find all records that have an occurrence that is inside a date range.

Eg. Find all records that have an occurrence between `2017-08-01T12:00:00` and `2017-09-01T12:00:00`.

```
{
    "repeats": {
        "rrule": "FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20170904T030000Z;COUNT=20;INTERVAL=1;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO",
        "occurrences": [
            {
                "uuid": "5445c067-1377-4636-9844-16b159caff1b",
                "date_range": {
                    "end": "2017-09-04T14:00:00+10:00",
                    "start": "2017-09-04T13:00:00+10:00",
                    "timezone": "Australia/Melbourne"
                }
            },
            {
                "uuid": "9a9a58ef-d697-4941-94d0-623915af87f3",
                "date_range": {
                    "end": "2017-11-13T14:00:00+11:00",
                    "start": "2017-11-13T13:00:00+11:00",
                    "timezone": "Australia/Melbourne"
                }
            },
            {
                "uuid": "4a310678-997a-4eb9-8bb9-faef80836c9f",
                "date_range": {
                    "end": "2017-11-27T14:00:00+11:00",
                    "start": "2017-11-27T13:00:00+11:00",
                    "timezone": "Australia/Melbourne"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "tickets": {
        "url": "",
        "title": ""
    },
}
```

I'm pretty lost at where to begin with, all I've been able to achieve is to get a record where the first occurrence start is not null (not very useful!):

```
posts = EventPost.where("document -> 'repeats' #> '{occurrences,0}' -> 'date_range' -> 'start' IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: If you need to do this kind of query, then you're better off creating a class that can respond to date_range with time objects, instead of saving everything in a jsonb field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql: Query Between time range using jsonb field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836025/postgresql-query-between-time-range-using-jsonb-field)

Comment: Follow EJ2015's advice if possible.  Note that the gin index type is essentially worthless for this type of query, and it'll end up being a complete table scan every single time.  If you can make the dates into fields you can use btree indices which will be useful for your query, making it dramatically faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do it this way:

```
start_datetime = DateTime.new(2017, 9, 4, 13)
end_datetime = DateTime.new(2017, 9, 4, 14)

EventPost.where(%{
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(document #> '{repeats,occurrences}') occurrences
    WHERE (occurrences -> 'date_range' ->> 'start')::timestamp >= ?
      AND (occurrences -> 'date_range' ->> 'end')::timestamp <= ?
 )
}, start_datetime, end_datetime)
```

This will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT "event_posts".* FROM "event_posts" WHERE (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(document #> '{repeats,occurrences}') occurrences
    WHERE (occurrences -> 'date_range'->> 'start')::timestamp >= '2017-09-04 13:00:00'
    AND (occurrences -> 'date_range' ->> 'end')::timestamp <= '2017-09-04 14:00:00'
  )
)
```

[`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) expands a JSON array into set of rows. In psql it looks like this:

```
 {"uuid": "5445c067-1377-4636-9844-16b159caff1b", "date_range": {"end": "2017-09-04T14:00:00+10:00", "start": "2017-09-04T13:00:00+10:00", "timezone": "Australia/Melbou
rne"}}                                    
 {"uuid": "9a9a58ef-d697-4941-94d0-623915af87f3", "date_range": {"end": "2017-11-13T14:00:00+11:00", "start": "2017-11-13T13:00:00+11:00", "timezone": "Australia/Melbou
rne"}}                                    
 {"uuid": "4a310678-997a-4eb9-8bb9-faef80836c9f", "date_range": {"end": "2017-11-27T14:00:00+11:00", "start": "2017-11-27T13:00:00+11:00", "timezone": "Australia/Melbou
rne"}}                                    
(3 rows)
```

From this rows we select only those that meet a condition, and if we have any, `EventPost` gets selected.

But I don't think that it's the best solution by performance, because of subquery, type conversions and jsonb processing. @EJ2015 and @Michael Chaney gave a good advice not to store `start` and `end` in jsonb.

Comment: in the end I went another route - I shifted them out of the jsonb field and into a separate class which was much much easier.